# "Nice to talk to" or "Nice to talk too"

Tags: british-english, homophones

One of my friends has corrected someone on their grammar on a social media site. And they think they should say "Nice to talk too". I think it is "Nice to talk to", because "too" is an adverb meaning "also"

Am I right? A more detailed explanation than mine would be great!

Comment: The usage in a sentence would be "you are nice to talk to/too" if that clarifies anything

Comment: Of course, there's the English Beat classic [Too Nice to Talk To](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnljPqBZq6M)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Nice to talk to* could mean *You are nice to speak with*, while *Nice to talk too* could mean *I also find it nice to talk*. In the case of *You are nice to talk to/too*, it is the former and not the latter.

Comment: Thanks! Just needed clearer clarification compared to what I could provide. Top job! :)

Comment: Yes, both have different meanings.